# Replacing elements in a string besides the first Occurence In Scala

Tags: regex, scala

Im relatively new to Regex and although I know Scala has a method of Utilizing Replace the items before first occurrence but i was wondering if there was a way to get rid of Items in a String After its First Occurrence in Scala.

For Example If i were to have a String Like

```html
"Hello. W.o.r.l.d"
```

How Would i go about deleting all Following W.

So that it would resemble something akin to

```html
"Hello. World"
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No fancy regex required. Just `split()` and then reconnect.

```
val noDots = "Hello. W.o.r.l.d".split("\\.")
val res = noDots.head + "." + noDots.tail.mkString  //res: String = Hello. World
```

This will work correctly if there is only one `.` in the text but if there is no `.` then it inserts one at the end of the string.

Answer (score 3):

Here's one approach using a mix of `Regex` pattern matching and `replace`:

```
val s = "Hello. W.o.r.l.d"

val pattern = """(.*?\.)(.*)""".r

s match {
  case pattern(a, b) => a + b.replace(".", "")
  case others => others
}
// res1: String = Hello. World
```

Note that if the string has no `.`, it'll be matched by `case others`.

Answer (score 0):

You could also try with indexOf and substring combination

```
scala> val x = "Hello. W.o.r.l.d"
x: String = Hello. W.o.r.l.d

scala> x.substring(0,x.indexOf(".")+1) + x.split("\\.").tail.mkString
res21: String = Hello. World

scala>
```